# UTF-8 codec can't decode byte 0xe9

Tags: python, python-3.x

So It seems that I'm getting an error in my code 
"Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: invalid continuation byte"
This one to be exact

and the code is

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
smtp_ssl_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp_ssl_port = 465
username = 'removed'
password = 'removed'
sender = username
targets = ["removed"]
msg = MIMEText("Test")
msg['Subject'] = "Test"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ', '.join(targets)
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL((smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(sender, targets, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Looking to fix it

Comment: *Where* does the error happen? Since we can't run your code for ourselves, that's the bare *minimum* of information we need to help you out.

Comment: The error happened in the line server= smtplib. SMTP_SSL...

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?